# MVC 3 ReturnUrl redirection not working

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a probably very silly question but I'll has it anyway.

Here is the code in my controller for logging in

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(LogonModel model, string ReturnUrl)
        {
            ReturnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"];
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (UserRepository.validLogin(model.Username, model.Password))
                {
                    UserLogRepository.createLogEntry("Log On", " has logged on to the Staff Portal.", "Entry/Exit");
                    if (ReturnUrl.Length > 1)
                    {
                        return Redirect(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "Home");
                    }
                }
                else
                {

                    ModelState.AddModelError("", Session["Error"].ToString());
                }
            }
            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return View(model);
        }
```

As you can see i'm just checking if the returnurl has a length for testing purposes before I lock it down more. My issue is I get an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." pointing to this line "if (ReturnUrl.Length > 1)"

Now the URL I have when a user has timed out from the site is this:
http://localhost/Dispatch2012/Staff/Home?ReturnUrl=Dispatch2012%2FStaff%2FCredential

As you can see, this is the standard redirect created by MVC 3 and i've tried to read the ReturnUrl as a standard query string but every time it says that object doesn't exist. What am I missing?

Comment: Which controller contains Index?

Answer (score 5):

The way your controller is set up is strange to me, but let's dive into it:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(LogonModel model, string returnUrl) //changed
    {
        ReturnUrl = returnUrl; //changed
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (UserRepository.validLogin(model.Username, model.Password))
            {
                UserLogRepository.createLogEntry("Log On", string.Format("{0} has logged on to the Staff Portal.", model.Username, "Entry/Exit"); //changed
                if (ReturnUrl.Length > 1) //this should use IsLocalUrl
                {
                    return Redirect(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]);
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "Home");
                }
            }
            else
            {

                ModelState.AddModelError("", Session["Error"].ToString());
            }
        }
        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

A few things:

1. Your `returnUrl` needs to be checked to make sure it's a Local URL. There are a number of ways of doing this, and since you're using ASP.NET MVC 3, [it's built in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.islocalurl%28v=vs.98%29.aspx).
2. Why are you pulling the ReturnUrl out of the querystring when (if you've set up your view correctly), it's already passed in?

Do you have the following in your view?

```
<%= Html.Hidden("returnUrl", Url.Encode(Url.Action("ActionToRedirectTo", "ControllerName", new { id = Model.Whatever}))) %>
```

If so, when it posts, it will automatically get sent to the `Index` Action as the `returnUrl` parameter.

I'm betting since it's not working, you aren't actually sending the ReturnUrl back correctly, check what I said about the view.  Oh, and make sure you're URL encoding the `ReturnUrl`.

Also, since it's a `HttpPost`, the querystring wouldn't have the return Url in it.